# why is everything heavily responding while transferring data to a 32GB USB stick?

Tags: debian, usb, nautilus

everything is literally everything including scrolling , switching apps , typing even moving pointer is very laggy , i'm using Debian Stretch with GNOME and nautilus (obviously)

Here's top output

```
root@www:~# top

top - 19:27:05 up 1 day,  3:15,  1 user,  load average: 5.53, 5.61, 3.84
Tasks: 229 total,   1 running, 228 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.8 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 25.0 id, 72.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  7945316 total,   102772 free,  2399920 used,  5442624 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8152572 total,  8152572 free,        0 used.  4927412 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                     
 7627 root      20   0   13168   2452   1856 S   4.7  0.0   0:32.63 mount.ntfs                  
 7609 rahman    20   0  980360  51112  36556 S   1.3  0.6   0:20.01 nautilus                    
12419 rahman    20   0 1510144  80536  32580 S   1.3  1.0   6:57.26 transmission-gt             
 5139 root      20   0  266576   5448   4592 S   0.7  0.1   8:46.92 iio-sensor-prox             
 5340 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.7  0.0   0:01.31 kworker/u16:9               
 7647 root      20   0   13356   2516   1816 S   0.7  0.0   0:04.50 mount.ntfs                  
 7844 rahman    20   0 2509544 283260  66824 S   0.7  3.6  50:20.60 gnome-shell                 
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.87 ksoftirqd/0                 
   16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:05.33 ksoftirqd/1                 
   28 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:06.55 ksoftirqd/3                 
   47 root      20   0       0      0      0 D   0.3  0.0   0:04.99 kswapd0                     
  217 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:05.00 jbd2/sda8-8                 
 7877 root      20   0       0      0      0 D   0.3  0.0   0:00.11 kworker/2:2                 
 8160 root      20   0   45032   3800   3044 R   0.3  0.0   0:00.04 top                         
    1 root      20   0  204824   7144   5256 S   0.0  0.1   0:08.84 systemd                     
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.08 kthreadd                    
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
```

my xorg intel configuration file is : (i use intel hd graphics ironlake)

```
root@www:~# cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf 
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod" "sna"
   Option      "DRI"         "3"
EndSection
```

if you need some sort of more info please leave a comment below, don't ignore.

Answer (score 3):

The clue is here:

```
%Cpu(s):  0.8 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 25.0 id, 72.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
```

72% of your CPU power is stuck waiting for I/O operations to complete.  If I had to guess, your USB medium is connected to a port running directly from the motherboard's chipset rather than a PCI card, and it's jumping to the front of the line.

Comment: i guess you're right,i tried another port and wa is almost same so i guess all of my USB ports run directly from the motherboard's chip-set  , is there any way to fix that even a little bit ?

Comment: Beside, I had 25% idle CPU so why did it act like its stuck at 100%

Comment: Not shown: the number of cores; if your GUI composter thread was on the same core as the USB I/O thread, for instance, that might cause this sort of thing.

Comment: That 72% of power is not stuck, really. It's just the percentage of time spent waiting for I/O doing nothing, basically a different type of idle.

Comment: If it's committed to waiting for an I/O operation to complete and cannot be allocated to other processes, that's close enough to 'stuck' or at the very least 'unavailable' for the purposes of this question, in my opinion.

Comment: That's what I'm pointing out: it isn't committed to anything, the CPU just happens to be idle when some process is waiting for I/O. If there was anything else to do, it would be scheduled. (Please mention my name when replying to my comments, so I get notified.)