# kernel panic then a spam from tracker-miner-f in syslog

Tags: debian, kernel-panic

Few hours later after [this issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397077/why-is-everything-heavily-responding-while-transferring-data-to-a-32gb-usb-stick) occurred, out of nowhere i got a some sort of a kernel panic for the first time !

lines were flying all the way up i couldn't read it properly, so i unplugged the laptop and restarted it , check my syslog and i've found this weird spam

```
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 16 (file:///home/rahman/Downloads/reaver-1.3/reaver-1.3/src/utils/common.c) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 17 (file:///home/rahman/Downloads/reaver-1.3/reaver-1.3/src/utils/os_none.c) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 18 (file:///home/rahman/Downloads/reaver-1.3/reaver-1.3/src/utils/eloop_none.c) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 19 (file:///home/rahman/Downloads/reaver-1.3/reaver-1.3/src/utils/ip_addr.h) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 20 (file:///home/rahman/Downloads/reaver-1.3/reaver-1.3/src/utils/trace.h) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 21 (file:///home/rahman/Downloads/reaver-1.3/reaver-1.3/src/utils/eloop.c) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 22 (file:///home/rahman/Downloads/reaver-1.3/reaver-1.3/src/utils/base64.c) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 23 (file:///home/rahman/Downloads/reaver-1.3/reaver-1.3/src/utils/common.h) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 24 (file:///home/rahman/Downloads/reaver-1.3/reaver-1.3/src/utils/pcsc_funcs.h) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Oct  9 23:19:03 www tracker-miner-f[4463]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 25 (file:///home/rahman/Downloads/reaver-1.3/reaver-1.3/src/utils/includes.h) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
```

it's not just those it keeps printing that all over the syslog
i scanned the directory with clamav hoping there is a malware or something that caused all that but it's clean

my uname -a output

```
Linux www 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.51-1 (2017-09-28) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

what was that ?

PS: sorry, i don't know where to get the kernel panic message so i took a picture of just the last bunch of lines before i unplugged it

[image]

Update : Now it completely frozen up and I had to unplug it.

Comment: the other message you posted shows `transmission` running.  I'm assuming that the messages above stem from the tracker gathering information about new files.  Although, I'm not sure that this is related to any kernel panic.

Comment: if so , what does transmission has to do with the old version of reaver i downloaded from github ? , also i updated the question i hope it got some clearer

Comment: new files downloaded, assumed with transmission.  Apparently not relevant, as the files were downloaded outside the program.  The rest of the statement still applies

Comment: Ok so it's irrelevant ,but still the main issue is the kernel panic

Comment: The kernel panic mentions the swapper going down, which means severe problems with memory management down the line. Any software throwing errors after that point may be entirely unrelated to problems with the software itself, but caused by parts of the kernel no longer functioning properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved, I noticed that the problems started to occur the day after installing kernel `4.9.0-4`, So I used kernel `4.9.0-3` and the problem disappeared, then reinstalled the kernel `4.9.0-4` and found an error I didn't notice last time

```
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.9.0-4 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.248+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
```

so I purged `bcmwl-kernel-source` and reinstalled the kernel again and the error disappeared and everything is now working fine, no kernel panics no freezings.

and yes: tracker-miner-f is irrelevant.