# `syslog` spammed by `dbus-daemon`, claims that unit `tracker-extract.service` is masked

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, syslog, tracker

[5.0.9-arch1-1-ARCH with gnome-desktop 3.32.1.2-1 and tracker 2.2.1]

This is a follow-up on a [previous answered question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515775/gnome-desktops-tracker-spams-syslog-at-boot), where I unmasked the `tracker-store.service`, which was spamming my syslog at boot already and disabled the search option in Nautilus from the GUI. I also erased the complete database index, with `$ tracker reset --hard`, as I never use Nautilus.

The message that spams my `syslog` is:

> dbus-daemon[1492]: [session uid=1000 pid=1492] Activation via systemd
>   failed for unit 'tracker-extract.service': Unit
>   tracker-extract.service is masked.

... most of those lines forming a repeat sequence, as obtained from: `$ sudo journalctl -b`. The number of occurences increases rapidly with time, at an coarsely estimated rate of 1200/min.

The truncated syslog listing is [here](https://clbin.com/LY530). (It is way too big to upload whole.) I checked that I actually have no `tracker-extract.service` unit `active`, `enabled`, or `masked`. The `tracker-extract` service unit does not appear in:

```
$ sudo systemctl list-dependencies --all | grep -e extract -e tracker
```

Comment: You can help answerers by showing whether you have the tracker-miners package installed, and using the `--user` flag to `systemctl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind this answer is simple. Also look at user name space, not just at system's namespace when it comes to troubleshooting `syslog`. The merit for reminding me of this is **entirely** @JdeBP's.

Following his suggestion, I used the `--user` flag to un-mask the service unit for the calling user, rather than by invoking the service manager of the system.

```
$ pacman -Ss tracker-miners
extra/tracker-miners 2.2.2-1 (gnome) [installed]
Collection of data extractors for Tracker/Nepomuk
```

confirms (if necessary) that `tracker-miners` is installed.

```
$ systemctl --user unmask tracker-extract.service
Removed /home/<USER>/.config/systemd/user/tracker-extract.service
$ systemctl --user list-unit-files tracker-extract.service
UNIT FILE               STATE
tracker-extract.service static
1 unit files listed.
```

resulted in the `tracker-extract` service not being flagged as "masked" by `dbus-daemon`. Spamming of my `syslog` stopped immediately afterwards.