# what is tracker-miner-f and how to stop it

Tags: top

I noticed lately that my computer heats up and the fans are louder than ever before and the battery life is shorter, so I rand `top`  to see usage of cpu and ram and i noticed two process that consume almost all of my cpu power

```
 PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                     
   4823 user+  20   0  361960  22132  17448 R  99,3   0,3   0:03.30 tracker-store                                                                                               
   1579 user+  39  19  759660 177600  18736 R  99,0   2,4  24:55.20 tracker-miner-f
```

I also rand `htop` along side and at any given time there are two or more fully utilized core in my 8 core cpu, all of this is happening right after i boot my system and I don't have any services enabled on boot (ssh,bluetooth,...etc)

what are these processes and is there any way to stop them

Comment: Also, for questions like this in the future, please remember to add your environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the Gnome tool that indexes your home so that searches in your file manager are faster. It's annoying as heck if you happen to be building software in your home directory, and somehow someone tries to read gigabytes of object files as they're created...

Uninstall it. I've not noticed a significant difference in search speed, and honestly, I very rarely use the file manager's search function anyways.

you can probably also revertibly disable it: [Gnome-desktop's 'tracker' spams syslog at boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/515775/gnome-desktops-tracker-spams-syslog-at-boot)

Comment: can you include how to uninstall it in the answer

Comment: I can't, because that depends on your Linux distro, which I can't know!

Comment: on Ubuntu: `sudo apt remove tracker-miner-fs`

Comment: It should be borne in mind that deleting `tracker-miner-fs` entails deleting nautilus, for example, as well as several other programs

Comment: @Никитос that's the thing, in multiple distro's that I've checked, it's just a suggestion or recommendation or enhancement, but not actually a hard dependency. That is an effect of the intentional decoupling of `tracker` and `miner` in `tracker`'s architecture.